# trying to use an regex inside firebase .where() to fillter users but only get an error message

Tags: javascript, regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basicly i am working on an whatsapp clone and i went into an problem when searching over the contacts of the current user.

here's the first code

```js
this._user.getContacts(this.el.inputSearchContacts.value);
```

this one is inside an function that when you press any letter or number while the input is focused it start to send what is inside the input to the "getContacts" function

```js
getContacts(fillter = ""){

        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        User.getContactsRef(this.email).where("nameLowerCase", ">=", (fillter)? fillter.match( /([a-z])\+w/gi) : fillter).onSnapshot(docs=>{
          here goes the rest of the function
        }
```

here is where an fillter is applied what it should do is get the name you put in the input and match it with the contacts names in the user contacts list to only show the ones that match, but here's where this error appear:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid query. Null supports only equality comparisons.
    at new FirestoreError (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js?:351:28)
    at Function.FieldFilter.create (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js?:9830:23)
    at CollectionReference.Query.where (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js?:22151:34)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/model/User.js?:87:41)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at User.getContacts (webpack:///./src/model/User.js?:85:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.eval (webpack:///./src/controller/WhatsAppController.js?:401:20)
FirestoreError @ index.cjs.js:351
FieldFilter.create @ index.cjs.js:9830
Query.where @ index.cjs.js:22151
eval @ User.js:87
getContacts @ User.js:85
eval @ WhatsAppController.js:401
```

so, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't supported.  Firestore doesn't offer regex searches at all.  You can only compare strings with `>=`, `==`, and `<=`.

The error message is telling you that your trinary expression:

```
(fillter)? fillter.match( /([a-z])\+w/gi) : fillter
```

yielded a null value, which isn't a valid value for the `>=` comparison you're asking Firestore to perform on the field.

Comment: So, is there any way i can reach the same objective? Before i was using . Where("nameLowerCase" >= fillter) but the problem was that if the name of an contact had the letter "A" for example It would show up don't matter where the "A" is, i want something more precise. Thanks by the way bro.

Comment: Your alternatives are to 1) filter the documents on the client by examining each field, 2) pre-compute the results of that regex for each document and store it as a boolean to query, 3) mirror the data into another database that does support regex (but won't scale massively like Firstore).

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i will try them.

Comment: well i used the first option and it worked perfectly , thanks!